# Unable to create Customer Payment Method through REST API

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

While trying to create the `Customer Payment Method` using REST API, I'm facing this issue : `Value Cannot be Empty`.
Below is the json that i'm using

```
{
    "CustomerID" : { "value" : "ARYA" },
    "PaymentMethod" : { "value" : "AMEX" },
    "ProcCenterID" : { "value" : "AUTDOTNET" },
    "CustomerPaymentMethodDetail" : [
    {
        "Name" : { "value" : "CCDNUM" },
        "Value" : { "value" : "5454545454545454" }
    },
    {
        "Name" : { "value" : "EXPDATE" },
        "Value" : { "value" : "102020" }
    },
    {
        "Name" : { "value" : "NAMEONCC" },
        "Value" : { "value" : "Test API" }
    },
    {
        "Name" : { "value" : "CVV" },
        "Value" : { "value" : "321" }
    }]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It could help to post the full error messages and stack trace when available. There's likely more information besides 'Value Cannot be Empty". Identifying which field can't be empty will be necessary.

Comment: A common alternative debugging approach would be to create the Customer Payment Method on screen using the same values you provide with REST. When saving the field with the missing value can be highlighted and flagged as an error. Once you know which field is missing a value you can add it in your REST query.

Comment: thanks for your reply and i have tried with the same field name in the UI and able to create It.